# How old was Shaul when he became king?

Tags: history, age, king-saul

Shaul had Yonatan and Michal who were around Dovid's age. So how old is Shaul? I could not find any meforesh that said anything about it. asking on a Jewish perspective. Thanks!

Comment: He was one year old. It's an explicit verse in Tanakh

Comment: For anyone who wants answer credit:  http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemuel_I/13.1#e0n7, http://biblehub.com/1_samuel/13-1.htm

Comment: כבן שנה- means that he was like a one year old, he was free from sins. but thank you so much!

Comment: also it doesnt explain how he can have 2 kids and one is at least old enough to get married to dovid.

Comment: http://www.hatanakh.com/en/node/30838

Comment: That "one year old" verse is a classic example of an ancient scribal error.  The newly found DSS version with the lost paragraph on Nahash the Ammonite is another.

Comment: there are no "scribal errors"- rashi clearly says that it was written that way to praise his purity

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Samuel_Scroll

Comment: @Gary is this verse available in any of the fragments?  Because if so, that would make for a good answer (if it contained a number).

Comment: Unfortunately, no, at least according to this site, which lists and translates all the verses in each of the Biblical scrolls - http://dssenglishbible.com/ScrollsSamuel.htm   There's only 4 Samuel scrolls(mistitled as Ruth for some reason on this page), mostly in pieces-so far! Hopefully the right piece will turn up in our days!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned, according to the pure Tanach, he was one year old.  The Mefarshim don't really think this is meant to be interpreted factually, and so they have a number of ways to explain this, see Shmuel and Sabbahillel's answers.

Edit: Never mind, they've been deleted.  See Meafrshim [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemuel_I/13.1#e0n7).

Being that no one else seems to be quoting this, I would like to quote the commentary attributed to Ri Kara, which quotes Seder Olam Rabbah (13) saying that he was 25 when he was anointed king:

> בן שנה שאול במלכו – שנינו בסדר עולם: שמואל אמר לשאול בשעה שמשחו: וירדת לפני הגלגל עד ויחזק בכנף מעילו ויקרע, ואומר קרע י״י את ממלכות ישראל מעליך היום, ואחר כך ויקח את קרן השמן וימשח אותו בקרב אחיו ותצלח רוח י״יא אל דוד ויקם שמואל וילך הרמתה. **והוא בן כ״ה שנה**. וזהו בן שנה שאול במלכו – כל זה עשה בשנה ראשונה שבא לשמואל ומשחו והכה לנחש העמוני.

However, our [versions of Seder Olam Rabbah 13](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%99%D7%92) have 29:

> (ש"א יג, א): "בֶּן שָׁנָה שָׁאוּל בְּמָלְכוֹ וְגוֹ'", שמואל אמר לשאול בשעה שמשחו (שם י, ח) "וירדת לפני הגלגל וגו' ", ירד שנה ראשונה והכה נחש העמוני, ומשחוהו ישראל, שניה ירד, ולא שמר הבטחתו, (שם יג, יג) "וַיֹּאמֶר שְׁמוּאֵל אֶל שָׁאוּל נִסְכָּלְתָּ (כי) לֹא (שמעת) שָׁמַרְתָּ וְגוֹ'", ואותו הפרק נמשח דוד, שנאמר (שם טז, א) "וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל שְׁמוּאֵל עַד מָתַי וְגוֹ'", ואחר כך (שם, יג) "וַיִּקַּח שְׁמוּאֵל אֶת קֶרֶן הַשָּׁמֶן וְגוֹ'", **והוא היה בן כ"ט שנים,**

Note that there are some Mefarshim that say he only started ruling a year after he was annointed, not sure if these dates are at anointing or ruling.

Comment: So, why did tanach write he was 1?

Comment: @Shmuel It's not the question asked (in fact, consider asking it yourself), but I included it in my answer in case people ask... "וזהו בן שנה שאול במלכו – כל זה עשה בשנה ראשונה שבא לשמואל ומשחו והכה לנחש העמוני."

Comment: i am still confused to how he had a son who could be a general in the army (i thought the minimum age was 20)

Comment: @Ailuropodamelanoleuca Why are you confused?

Comment: if shaul was 25 or 29 when he became king he couldn't have had a son who was at least twenty. he would have had to have him at the age of five or nine.

Comment: Ish Boshes is described as 40 when he became king, immediately or shortly after Shaul died. Presumably Shaul would then have to have been at least in his fifties, in which case, according to this answer, he would have reigned for 25+ years. From his anointment to his death, only a handful of events are described, so most of his reign must have been pretty uneventful then.